# Prevent braces in BASH to create sub-shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, braces

I need braces to specify **evaluation priority** of expressions, but I don't want braces to create sub-scripts. Look what happens when that example code is ran:

## Example script

```
#!/bin/bash

false || (echo "First" && exit 1)
false || (echo "Second" && exit 2)
exit 3
```

## Output

```
First
Second
```

It seems that braces create sub-scripts, where exit doesn't cause the main script to exit.

What is the most elegant way to do what I want? Preferably without blocks and nesting. Thanks!

Comment: Is removing the parentheses not enough for you? I know it's not proper arithmetic logic, but it will evaluate across in order, and should achieve what I think it is supposed to.

Comment: @Wally - yes, in that specific example it would fit, but I really would like to know, how to prioritize expressions (in general) without creating sub-shells.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These `()` are parentheses, and they launch a subshell

These `{}` are braces, and they are for grouping within the current shell. `exit` will exit your script.

Note the whitespace requirements are more stringent (`{` needs to be followed by whitespace; `}` needs to be preceded by a semicolon plus whitespace, or a newline)

```
false || { echo foo; echo bar; }     # this is OK
false || {echo foo; echo bar}        # not OK
```

See [Grouping Commands](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Grouping) in the manual for the details.

Comment: `}` needs to be preceded by a command separator, regardless of whether it's a newline, semicolon, or ampersand.

Comment: Thank you, it works! I even skimmed over the topic of "grouping in BASH" some time ago, but didn't associated it with evaluation priority.